# R S4 class union of class unions

Tags: r, r-s4

I am trying to establish a union of class unions to facilitate method dispatch. The following reprex does exactly what I want when executed in the global environment, but as soon as I put this code into a package, the last line, `f(new("a"))`, throws an error that it is unable to find an inherited method.

```
setClass("x", slots = list(slot ="character"))
setClass("y", slots = list(slot ="character"))
setClass("a", slots = list(slot ="character"))
setClass("b", slots = list(slot ="character"))
setClassUnion("xy", c("x", "y"))
setClassUnion("ab", c("a", "b"))
setClassUnion("xyab", c("xy", "ab"))
setGeneric("f", function(object, ...) standardGeneric("f"))
setMethod("f", "xyab", function(object, ...) print("hi!"))

## print's "hi!" as expected
f(new("a"))
```

what am I missing?

to facilitate reproduction in a fresh R session, this reproduces the issue:

```
library(devtools)
fn <- "codefile.R"
writeLines(
    c(
        "setClass('x', slots = list(slot ='character'))",
        "setClass('y', slots = list(slot ='character'))",
        "setClass('a', slots = list(slot ='character'))",
        "setClass('b', slots = list(slot ='character'))",
        "setClassUnion('xy', c('x', 'y'))",
        "setClassUnion('ab', c('a', 'b'))",
        "setClassUnion('xyab', c('xy', 'ab'))",
        "setGeneric('f', function(object, ...) standardGeneric('f'))",
        "setMethod('f', 'xyab', function(object, ...) print('hi!'))"
    ),
    con = fn
)

package.skeleton(code_files = "codefile.R")
devtools::load_all("anRpackage")
f(new("a"))
```

Comment: to be clear, are you running `f` as part of the package load script, or at the terminal after having called `library(myPackage)`? When I ran your second code block, my function printed "hi!" (which I think is what you want it to do)

Comment: at the terminal after calling `library(myPackage)` - interesting that you do not see the error, you are correct that I am expecting the function to print "hi!". Are you sure you had a fresh R session? If you run the first block without closing R then it will work because the class definitions are in the .Globalenv

Comment: I didn't run the first code block at all, only the second. Perhaps that is the problem, that you had things lingering over from the first block that got in the way?

Comment: Nope -I ran it in a fresh session... quite peculiar - did you load the package with library or devtools?

Comment: I used `devtools`. I literally ran your second code block as is and never ran the first.

Comment: What’s your sessionInfo()?

Comment: it's too big to post in a comment but I am R 3.5.0 under MacOs 10.14

Comment: thanks! - running fine for me in R 3.4.3, so this is rapidly seeming like more of an r-devel issue: 3.6.0 is where it was breaking for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per R-devel, this is resolved in 4.0:

https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Possible-Regression-in-setClassUnion-between-3-5-0-and-3-6-0-td4761507.html